# Ajax and Javascript upload progress and status in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML file upload form which uploads files in php post method.

The form consists of showing a message ( Upload in Progress ) after clicking the upload submit button.

The HTML form:

```
    <!-- upload boxes -->
    <div class="tabmain">

        <ul class="tabnav">
            <!-- First-Tab -->
            <li title="{lang.DOWNLOAD_F}"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><i class="fa lnk-icon-0"></i><em>{lang.DOWNLOAD_F}</em></a></li>
            <!-- @First-Tab -->

            <!--you-can-add-another-tab-here-->

        </ul>

        <!-- First-Box -->
        <div class="tabcon" title="{lang.DOWNLOAD_F}">
        <div class="go_up clfx">
            <!-- upload normal -->
            <LOOP NAME=FILES_NUM_LOOP>
            <div class="up-input clfx" id="up_{{i}}"><div class="input-group">  <label class="input-group-btn">
                <input id="fileID" class="file" type="file" name="file_{{i}}_" data-number="{{i}}" style="{{show}}" onchange="readURL_file_(this,'.file-icon-{{i}}','#up_{{i}}','#info_list_{{i}}');" />
                <span class="btn"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <em> Choose a File </em></span>
                <span class="file-icon"><i></i><img class="file-icon-{{i}}" src="{STYLE_PATH}img/blank.png" alt=""></span>
                <a href="#" class="reset-input"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a> </label></div>

            </div>
            <ul class="info-up_{{i}} file-info clfx" id="info_list_{{i}}"></ul>
            </LOOP>
            <div class="agree"><span>{terms_msg}</span></div>
            <div class="bn_up"><input type="submit" id="submitr" name="submitr" value=" {lang.DOWNLOAD_F}" onclick="upload_image();"/></div>
            <!-- @upload normal -->
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- @First-Box -->

        <!--you-can-add-another-box-here-->

    </div>
    <!-- @upload boxes -->
```

Now I want to show the upload speed and the progress or status of the upload when I click the submit button, Noting that I already tried this solution :

I had used this javascript code :

```
<script>
function upload_image() 
{
var bar = $('#bar');
var percent = $('#percent');
$('#uploader').ajaxForm({
beforeSubmit: function() {
  document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display="block";
  var percentVal = '0%';
  bar.width(percentVal)
  percent.html(percentVal);
},

uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
  var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
  bar.width(percentVal)
  percent.html(percentVal);
},

success: function() {
  var percentVal = '100%';
  bar.width(percentVal)
  percent.html(percentVal);
},

complete: function(xhr) {
  if(xhr.responseText)
  {
    document.getElementById("output_image").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
  }
}
}); 
}
</script>
```

and Put this in the HTML form:

```
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
<div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
<div class='percent' id='percent1'>0%</div>
</div>
<div id='output_image'>
```

The upload is still working, But the progress bar doesn't work and never appear in the page, Also, the javascript part makes the upload refresh the page instead of showing download link of the uploaded file, since the PHP upload script functions to show the download link of files.

So my problem is, What should I change in the javascript code to make the Progress bar and the upload speed shows in the page without refreshing the page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code, take a look, maybe will be for your help:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        addThumbnail(response);
        $("h1").text("Feldolgozás....");
    },
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        // Upload progress
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            //Do something with upload progress
            console.log(percentComplete);
            // console.log(Math.round(percentComplete*100));
            }
        }, false);
        // Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            // Do something with download progress
            console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. I already tried similar code with POST in javascript and didn't work, Can you please try to edit your code to fit my HTML form to try it? I am very bad at javascript